# Manhwa about a cursed knight and a priest who takes care of him

Tags: story-identification, manga

I'm trying to find the name of a manhwa that I read a while ago. The story it's about a blonde knight who after defeating the demon lord got cursed with a kind of illness. For some reason, the church commanded a young priest to go to take care of him.

The priest has black hair and his skin is light brown.

I don't remember so much apart from that, maybe the now-retired knight could have had a pet (a fantastic one for sure) but I don't recall exactly about it. I just remember how pitiful he was.